# Comparison literal character like mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have this table:

```
|--------------------------|------------------|
|      tab1                |     tab2         |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Guerreo Reyna            |         1        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Marroquin Bocanegra      |         10       |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Calderon Salguero        |         10       |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| De la Cruz Barrios       |    1,2,3,4       |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Guillen Cornet           |        1,3       |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Luna MendivÃ­             |         10       |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| Chang Ruiz               |         1        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
```

when I do this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.familias,
                f.apellidos,
                i.nombre
FROM familias AS f
INNER JOIN integrantes AS i ON f.familias = i.familia
WHERE tab2 LIKE '%1%'
  OR tab2 LIKE '%3%'
ORDER BY 1
```

I need only return those who have the 1 and 3, not 10

Thank you so much

Comment: If you will use `%1%` the query will return `10` as well just remove `%%` from your `WHERE` claus

Comment: @GHOST93 as you do if you have this case 2,1,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.familias,
                f.apellidos,
                i.nombre
FROM familias AS f
INNER JOIN integrantes AS i ON f.familias = i.familia
WHERE find_in_set('1',`tab2`) and find_in_set('3',`tab2`)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: `Heading 2` should be quoted. and '10' should also be included.

Comment: @Maverick2786 What you say I dont understand

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake in the query works perfect
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE concat(',', tab2, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
  OR  concat(',', tab2, ',') LIKE '%,3,%'
ORDER BY 1
```